# How to append Html to the corresponding div with same class

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can I append the Html to corresponding div which has the same data-attribute value? 
I pass a data-attribute-value to the moda when the button is clicked and it is also added to the submit button in the modal to pass the valu back again. I want to find the element with that data-attribut value and append the html to it.
            Image (1)

```
        <button data-media-select="2" data-gallery-position="2"  type="button" class="btn btn-success media-modal-btn" >Image (1)</button>
        <div data-gallery-position="2" class="popup-gallery"></div>

        <button data-media-select="5" data-gallery-position="3" type="button" class="btn btn-warning media-modal-btn" >Images (5)</button>
        <div data-gallery-position="3"  class="popup-gallery"></div>
```

Jquery:

```
    $mediaModalBtn.on('click',function(){
        var   mediaSelect = $(this).data('media-select')
            , galleryPosition = $(this).data('gallery-position');
        $.ajax({
            url: 'http://example.com/abc/media',
            success: function (result) {
                $( "#mediaModalFiles" ).html( result );
                $('#mediaModal').modal('show');
                $('#selectMediaBtn').attr('data-gallery-position',galleryPosition);
                $('#mediaModal').checkboxes('max', mediaSelect);
                $("#selectMediaBtn").attr('disabled','disabled');
            }
        });
    });
    $('body').delegate('input[name="media[]"]','change',function () {
        var media = new Array();
        $('input[name="media[]"]:checked').each(function () {
            media.push(this.value);
        });
        if ( media.length > 0 )
        {
            $("#selectMediaBtn").removeAttr('disabled');
        } else {
            $("#selectMediaBtn").attr('disabled','disabled');
        }
    });
    $('body').delegate('#selectMediaBtn', 'click', function () {
        var   galleryPosition = $(this).data('gallery-position')
            , targetGalleryPosition = $('.popup-gallery[data-gallery-position = "'+galleryPosition+'" ]')
            , media = new Array();
        $('input[name="media[]"]:checked').each(function () {
            media.push(this.value);
        });
        if ( media.length > 0 )
        {
            $.ajax({
                url: 'http://example.com/abc/media/fetch',
                data: { media : media },
                success: function (result) {
                    $('#mediaModal').modal('hide');
                    $( targetGalleryPosition ).html( result );
                }
            });
        }
    });
```

Comment: whats the question? what part of your code isnt working?

Comment: I think you are looking for `$(".class[data-attribute=value]")` to select the given box but I don't really want to decipher your code... (EDIT actually you are doing that so whats not working?)

Comment: maybe what he's doing is Q&A

Comment: I want to find the element by $(".class[data-attribute=value]") and append the html to it. I don't know how to do it.

Comment: please make a [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net), large parts of your code are missing, your syntax is fine and we cant pinpoint the problem without seeing the whole thing

Answer (score 0):

you can use **[.filter()](http://api.jquery.com/filter/)** to filter the elements that have the same value in their gallery position data attribute:

```js
$(function(){
    $(".div_btn").click(function(){
        $(".galery_item").removeClass("selected");
        var pos=$(this).data("gallery-position");
        $(".galery_item").filter(function(){
            return $(this).data("gallery-position")==pos;
        }).addClass("selected");
    });
});
```

```css
.div_btn{
    display:inline-block;
    width:100px;
    height:100%;
    text-align:center;
    border:5px ridge gray;
    cursor:pointer;
}
.div_btn:active{
    background:green;
}
.galery_item{
    display:inline-block;
    width:50px;
    height:50px;
    text-align:center;
    border:5px ridge gray;
}
.selected{
    background:red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="div_btn" data-gallery-position="top">top</div>
<div class="div_btn" data-gallery-position="middle">middle</div>
<div class="div_btn" data-gallery-position="bottom">bottom</div>
<hr/>
<div class="galery_item" data-gallery-position="top"></div>
<div class="galery_item" data-gallery-position="top"></div>
<div class="galery_item" data-gallery-position="top"></div>
<div class="galery_item" data-gallery-position="top"></div>
<div class="galery_item" data-gallery-position="top"></div>
<br/>
<div class="galery_item" data-gallery-position="middle"></div>
<div class="galery_item" data-gallery-position="middle"></div>
<div class="galery_item" data-gallery-position="middle"></div>
<div class="galery_item" data-gallery-position="middle"></div>
<div class="galery_item" data-gallery-position="middle"></div>
<br/>
<div class="galery_item" data-gallery-position="bottom"></div>
<div class="galery_item" data-gallery-position="bottom"></div>
<div class="galery_item" data-gallery-position="bottom"></div>
<div class="galery_item" data-gallery-position="bottom"></div>
<div class="galery_item" data-gallery-position="bottom"></div>
```